# How I display title in categories only one title in one blogpost?

Tags: codeigniter

Hi all i'm a new of codigniter I create post and join two table I want to show categories title only one in my blog post .but it not folow me.it show many title categories in every post.
My Code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Site extends CI_Controller {
function index(){
    $this->home();
}
function home(){
    $this->load->view('header_view');
    $this->load->view('slide_view');
    $this->load->view('crumb_view');
    $this->load->view('footer_view');
}

function menu(){
    $this->load->model('tinjeat_md');
    $data["menu_pro"] = $this->tinjeat_md->menu_get();


    $this->load->view('header_view');
    $this->load->view('crumb_view');
    $this->load->view('menu_view',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer_view');
}
```

}

```
<?php
class Tinjeat_md extends CI_Model{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
function menu_get(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('menu','categories_menu');
    $this->db->join('categories_menu','menu.cate_id=
    categories_menu.id','left'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
   }
  }
  ?>
```

View:

```
<div class="menu">
<?php foreach ($menu_pro as $value): ?>
<p class="title_cate">
    <?php echo $value->cate_name_menu; ?>
</p>
<div class="menu_image">
 <?php
  echo img(array(
  'src'=>'./images/'.$value->image,
  'width'=>'220px',
  'height'=>'150px'
  ));
   ?>
    </div>
  <div class="menu_description">
  <h3><?php echo $value->title; ?></h3>
  <p><?php echo $value->description; ?></p>
  <p>Prices:<?php echo $value->prices; ?></p>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
My database:
categories_menu
-id
-cate_menu_name

    menu
    -id_menu
    -title
    -image
    -description
    -prices
    -cate_id
```

Comment: Without code (and db tables structure) - no one can help you. Didn't down voted your question - but, i am afraid - many will do so.... Edit question, and add your current code, explain your db structure, etc, etc...

Comment: How I earn 10reputation

Comment: what is your email I want to post My iamge to you help me pls?

Comment: Post code, you (and we) don't need images...

Answer (score 0):

In your model.Try like this.

```
function menu_get(){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('menu');
  $this->db-join('categories_menu','menu.cate_id=categories_menu.id','left'); 
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}
```

for [user guide](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

you can check your sql query by using `$this->db->last_query()`.